# Using data.table in package - fail on check

Tags: r, package, data.table

I want to use data.tables as a backbone in a package that I wrote.

As I don't want to used `::` all the time (and avoid the complications with `[` and `:=` operators), I include data.table as a Depends and not as an Import in DESCRIPTION to be able to use all dt functions directly.

If I build the package everything works fine but running a "check" results in the error (from DTTest.Rcheck/00install.out):

```
* installing *source* package ‘DTTest’ ...
** R
** preparing package for lazy loading
** help
*** installing help indices
** building package indices
** testing if installed package can be loaded
Error : package ‘data.table’ required by ‘DTTest’ could not be found
Error: loading failed
Execution halted
ERROR: loading failed
```

The only function in this package is this

```
#' Creates a data.table
#'
#' @return a data.table
#' @export
#'
#' @examples
#' create_dt()
create_dt <- function() {
  dt <- data.table(x = 1:10)
  dt[, x_2 := x^2]
  return(dt[])
}
```

And DESCRIPTION contains `Depends: data.table`, otherwise the files are the standard RStudio new package-files.

You can find the whole package here: https://github.com/DavZim/DTTest

Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: Have you tried `data.table::data.table(x = 1:10)`

Comment: Put data.table in Imports and import the package in NAMESPACE. That's what I do and it works well for my one package that is available on CRAN.

Comment: @Ronald What package is that? I tried doing your recommendations and it didnt work (see the latest commit on github)

@akrun The issue comes with the `:=` operator and other data.table operations. With other packages I would do just that.

Comment: Please study Writing R Extensions. Correct syntax is import(data.table). Why did you add quotes?

Comment: Thanks for the hint towards the quotes. Unfortunately that was not the origin of the error (I have updated the repo). Also I have read the parts in Writing R Extensions and have looked at the text2vec-package (that has the same import data.table construct) and to my understanding it should work now, but I still get the error `Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘DTTest’ in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]): there is no package called ‘data.table’` (needless to say data.table is installed).

Comment: All I do is add data.table to Imports in DESCRIPTION and tell roxygen2 to `#' @import data.table`. However, your package builds and loads fine on my system. That indicates that you have a problem in your setup, possibly with your `.libPaths()`.

Comment: Wonderful, that gave me the right hint, thanks a lot! R tried to search data.table in my first libPath, while I mostly use another path. Installing dt in the first path solved the issue!

Comment: Feel free to post this as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some helpful comments from Roland, I found the solution to my problem. It was indeed related to my `.libPaths()` and not with the code.

When checking the package R tried to search for the packages inside the first library in `.libPaths()`. As it happens, I have four paths (`/usr/local/...`, `/usr/lib/R/site-library`, `/usr/lib/R/library`, and `/home/user/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.4`) and data.table is installed inside the last one.

The solution (more like a workaround at this stage) was to install data.table in the first one.

To do this, I executed R with admin privileges (`sudo R` in my case) and installed data.table with `install.packages("data.table", lib = .libPaths()[1])`.

Now the check pass as expected!